# Set supplementary group ids of a user in linux using C

Tags: c++, c, linux, usergroups

There is `setgroups(size_t size, const gid_t *list)` method in C which would allow me to set the supplementary group ids of the calling process.

Question 1:

But in order run this we need to have proper rights so the only way I got to run this program without getting **Operation not permitted** error is to run it using root. But does that mean using this method we could only set the groups of root??

Question 2:

On the other hand what I intend to do is given a particular user and a list of gid's I want to set the given gid's as the supplementary groups to given user. Is there a method defined for this in C/C++?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As I recall `setgroups` can only be called by a privileged user.  This doesn't necessarily mean root but a process with CAP_SETGID privileges.  root can obviously set any gid not just its own groups.  I'm not 100% certain of your 2nd question.  setgroups is probably what you want but I don't remember the permissions issues involved.  You should probably look into the "capabilities" literature.

Answer (score 0):

Technically under Linux you need the `CAP_SETGID` capability, which need not be root (but normally is).

Note that this works with the effective `gid`, not the actual `gid`. Note also the actual / effective `gid` of the calling process is not necessarily the same as the actual / effective `uid`. You should have a look at the manpages for `setuid`, `seteuid`, `setgid` and `setegid` for more details, but one scenario would be for a SUID program to `setegid` back to an unprivileged group then use `setgroups`.